# text flows out of bootstrap 4 card

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I am trying to place two words on left and right side of bootstrap 4 card...

However the problem is that :
[image]

the text "Choro" flows out of the card body...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="align-middle">
<div class="container">
            <div class="card card-1">
                <p class="card-text">




                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                  <dt class="col-md-10 col-md-push-"><h1>Choro</h1></dt>
                  <dd class="col-md-1"><h1>Boy</h1></dd>
                 </dl>


                </p>                
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            </div>

<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

and custom.css code is:

```
.align-middle {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.card-1 {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }
```

What am i doing wrong?
even putting another container tag inside card doesn't works

**EDIT**

It looks now:
[image] Thank You @G.L.P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do few changes in your HTML structure like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17384/)**

You need to add `card-block` after `card` `div`

```
 <div class="card-text">    
        <div class="card-block">   
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt class="col-md-10"><h1>Choro</h1></dt>
            <dd class="col-md-1">
              <h1>Boy</h1></dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Edit**: .dl-horizontal has margin-left & right in negative values, So change the class name / update it like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17387/)**

```
.dl-horizontal {
    margin-right: 0rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you... but it helped only little... now text is no longer out of card but instead its on the card boundary... I want it quite inside...and col-md-push-1 is solution but it pushes too much inside and i want it little less